# Is this app development time realistic?

Tags: mobile, estimation

So I'm asked to estimate the development of an android app.

It's an app with some simple local database support, and a few views and sound playing, config saving. No design, just android gui.

I broke it down in tasks and made an estimate of around 105 hours from start till deployment.

Now since this is one of my first apps im making for which I'm asked to make a fixed cost estimate I'm a bit confused about how to do this.

Is 105 hours too much? I know you can't answer this but this will be an app of about 10K euro's this way. Is this a bit realistic or is this totally out of proportions?

It would be a bit of a shame to have to client laughing his ass off when I propose this.

So anybody who can help me a bit with this, and how do you estimate the cost when asked for a fixed price.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your customer asked you to estimate delivery date but not an effort in hours. In other words, in case of fixed price and specified job, a customer may negotiate only delivery date. A developer (you, in this case) needs to estimate an effort and decide how to put this effort into timeframe to secure comfortable delivery date. It is also worth thinking whether the estimated effort is actually payed off by the fixed price. Plus, if your customer wants delivery earlier, you may consider to ask for bigger price and hire second developer to help you and pay him. The book "Software Estimation: Demystifying the Black Art" explains this 'science' is details.

If your customer is really interested in estimation of effort, I would ask him why he needs it...